# selenium webdriver sends the text value very slow on IE browser

Tags: selenium

It is showing error message."unable to find element on closed window" & warning[the server did not provide any stacktrace information]. I have tried with 32 bit IE driver server & zoom the window to 100%, tried few other settings too of security and LAN but didn't work out.

```
else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
    String browser_Path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Browser";

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
    capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.loglevel", "TRACE");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.logfile", "log\\selenium.log");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",browser_Path+"\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: Question header mentions `webdriver sends the text value very slow on IE`. Can we see the relevant code please?

Comment: Use latest IEDriverServer.exe and update the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe /T
```

you might have running IEDriverServer process in the system, use the above code in cmd and check again.

Above code removes all IEDriverServer.exe

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to share the IDE,Selenium logs or IE logs ? I see that you have those enabled in your run.

Just check 
- if Java version is 64 bit than IE 64 bit should be used.
- if java version is 32 bit than IE 32 bit should be used.